# how to add subdomain for SharePoint apps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have given a DNS entry with SharePoint, now for SharePoint apps it says that we must have sub domain to install apps , so I wish to know where to have this sub domain entry ? should it be the sub domain of SharePoint web instance in IIS or something to do with Domain controller or DNS server. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below image shows how to set up app environment

[image]

Detailed explanation

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I don't have a domain , its installed on premises and from AD I gave it name as http://sharepoint